# Set 1 IP for each docker service

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Assuming that I have a swarm cluster. I run a web service like:
[image: Docker Swarm web service]

Now I want to use IP 192.168.xx.xx as IP of service (we can use browser connect to our service). How can I do that? I don't want to publish port of each container to host because We will have more than 1 IP address for a service like 192.168.99.100:3000 and 192.168.99.101:3000.
Sorry for my bad english
PS: I use docker tool-box 17.06 on window server 2012

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/v1.5/articles/networking/#binding-ports

Comment: I don't want to bind container's to host's port directly. I want to use overlay network's virtual IP as service's IP and docker swarm internal load-balancer as service load-balancer.

Answer (score 1):

Traeffik would be perfect for this, as it hooks into Docker Swarm as a backend.

Docs: https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/swarm/

Answer (score 0):

1 option could be setup a reverse proxy like nginx which has a public IP and that points to the overlay service that you have created.

Comment: I used HAproxy instead. It worked fine but it have a bottleneck in load-balancer. So I tried keepalive as a solution but I stuck at VIP. I use this solution as an alternative solution.